# Keep whitespace intact when reading txt files in

Tags: android, kotlin, ascii, whitespace, text-formatting

I'm trying to build a TXT reader app using Volley. 
The problem is when I pull the txt file and set the textview text to the response, it rips off some of the whitespaces.

I tried using `Html.fromhtml()` with `pre` tags and `white-space:pre` css.
I also tried using different fonts, both external(Adobe Source Code Pro) and internal(Monospace).

Here is the example txt file http://textfiles.com/100/adventur.txt

And here is how I pull the file to the Textview via Volley.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "http://textfiles.com/100/adventur.txt"
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        textView.text = response
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })
```

It should look like this https://i.ibb.co/Jyq8PFZ/Screenshot-from-2019-01-11-19-56-30.png

But it looks like this https://i.ibb.co/3TgKd38/Screenshot-from-2019-01-11-19-53-50.png

Could it be related to presenting ASCII art properly on a textview?

What is the best way to present a proper txt file reading experience?

Comment: Try replacing tabs with spaces prior to populating the TextView.

Comment: I tried using response.replace("\t", 4-SPACES) and results are pretty much the same.

Comment: I took a closer look and it seems to be font dependent. I tried pasting into Word, and if you use Courier New, then it displays correctly. Paste it into something like Sublime, and you get what you are seeing in your app.

Comment: Like I said, I tried with different fonts and results are same inside the app. Although Sublime and Word are different programs that interpret text differently, so I don't think it's a reasonable experiment. Thanks for trying.